# How to customize/modify JSON Response from object query result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sql-server, object

project using : nodejs, expressjs and database mssql 2000 with node-mssql

I have an object sample resulted from query table as follow. the length of object will vary depend on different "model code"

```
 
  [
  {
    poNumber: '002',
    modelCode: 'SM-A536EZWHXID',
    orderQuantity: '1',
    invoiceQuantity: null,
    price: '1000',
    totalPrice: '1000',
    receivedDate: 'Mar 26 2023  3:26AM',
    status: null,
    remarks: null
  },
  {
    poNumber: '002',
    modelCode: 'SM-A536EZWHXID',
    orderQuantity: '1',
    invoiceQuantity: null,
    price: '1000',
    totalPrice: '1000',
    receivedDate: 'Mar 26 2023  3:26AM',
    status: null,
    remarks: null
  },
  {
    poNumber: '002',
    modelCode: 'SM-A536EZOGXID',
    orderQuantity: '1',
    invoiceQuantity: null,
    price: '1000',
    totalPrice: '1000',
    receivedDate: 'Mar 26 2023  3:26AM',
    status: null,
    remarks: null
  }
  ]
```

with corresponding Json

```
  [
  {
    "poNumber": "002",
    "modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID",
    "orderQuantity": "1",
    "invoiceQuantity": null,
    "price": "1000",
    "totalPrice": "1000",
    "receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM",
    "status": null,
    "remarks": null
  },
  {
    "poNumber": "002",
    "modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID",
    "orderQuantity": "1",
    "invoiceQuantity": null,
    "price": "1000",
    "totalPrice": "1000",
    "receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM",
    "status": null,
    "remarks": null
  },
  {
    "poNumber": "002",
    "modelCode": "SM-A536EZOGXID",
    "orderQuantity": "1",
    "invoiceQuantity": null,
    "price": "1000",
    "totalPrice": "1000",
    "receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM",
    "status": null,
    "remarks": null
  }
  ]
```

But the client need Json in this format

```
  {
    "poNumber": "002",
    "items : [
  {
    "modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID",
    "orderQuantity": "1",
    "invoiceQuantity": null,
    "price": "1000",
    "totalPrice": "1000",
    "receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM",
  },
  {
    "modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID",
    "orderQuantity": "1",
    "invoiceQuantity": null,
    "price": "1000",
    "totalPrice": "1000",
    "receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM",
  },
  {
    "modelCode": "SM-A536EZOGXID",
    "orderQuantity": "1",
    "invoiceQuantity": null,
    "price": "1000",
    "totalPrice": "1000",
    "receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM",
  }
  ],
    "status": null,
    "remarks": null
  }
```

it is look alike grouping into :

header part : "poNumber"
body part   : with label "items" and its item "modelCode", "orderQuantity", "invoiceQuantity, "price", "totalPrice", receivedDate"
footer part : "status" and "remarks"

How can i generate object from table or modify json to get json structure as needed like that?

modify json and manipulate query result but did not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to group by:

- Create a Map keyed by `poNumber` and with as corresponding value the target object structure with `items` an empty array and `status` and `remarks` properties.
- Iterate the data to populate the `items` array for the entry retrieved from that map by `poNumber`
- Extract the values from the Map.

```js
const data =  [{"poNumber": "002","modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID","orderQuantity": "1","invoiceQuantity": null,"price": "1000","totalPrice": "1000","receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM","status": null,"remarks": null},{"poNumber": "002","modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID","orderQuantity": "1","invoiceQuantity": null,"price": "1000","totalPrice": "1000","receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM","status": null,"remarks": null},{"poNumber": "002","modelCode": "SM-A536EZOGXID","orderQuantity": "1","invoiceQuantity": null,"price": "1000","totalPrice": "1000","receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM","status": null,"remarks": null}];

const map = new Map(data.map(({poNumber, status, remarks}) => 
    [poNumber, {poNumber, items: [], status, remarks}]
));
for (const {poNumber, status, remarks, ...rest} of data) {
    map.get(poNumber).items.push(rest);
}
const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data =  [{"poNumber": "002","modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID","orderQuantity": "1","invoiceQuantity": null,"price": "1000","totalPrice": "1000","receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM","status": null,"remarks": null},{"poNumber": "002","modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID","orderQuantity": "1","invoiceQuantity": null,"price": "1000","totalPrice": "1000","receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM","status": null,"remarks": null},{"poNumber": "002","modelCode": "SM-A536EZOGXID","orderQuantity": "1","invoiceQuantity": null,"price": "1000","totalPrice": "1000","receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM","status": null,"remarks": null}];

const map = new Map(data.map(({poNumber, status, remarks}) => 
    [poNumber, {poNumber, items: [], status, remarks}]
));
for (const {poNumber, status, remarks, ...rest} of data) {
    map.get(poNumber).items.push(rest);
}
const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result);
```

@trincot thank you for your response

I try it in my vscode, but why the result is like  this?

```
[
  {
    poNumber: '002',
    items: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    status: null,
    remarks: null
  }
]
```

** Edited/Updated**
Result above from standalone execution

But when i integrated into my code, result is just perfect as desired

Case Resolved

Answer (score 0):

@vimmuth, thank you for your response

this is result in my vscode

```
    {
  "002": {
    "poNumber": "002",
    "items": [
      {
        "modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID",
        "orderQuantity": "1",
        "invoiceQuantity": null,
        "price": "1000",
        "totalPrice": "1000",
        "receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM"
      },
      {
        "modelCode": "SM-A536EZWHXID",
        "orderQuantity": "1",
        "invoiceQuantity": null,
        "price": "1000",
        "totalPrice": "1000",
        "receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM"
      {
        "modelCode": "SM-A536EZOGXID",
        "orderQuantity": "1",
        "invoiceQuantity": null,
        "price": "1000",
        "totalPrice": "1000",
        "receivedDate": "Mar 26 2023  3:26AM"
      }
    ],
    "status": null,
    "remarks": null
  }
}
```

How to remove excessive line number #2?

"002": {

thank you